# Phone number validation problems

Tags: javascript, phone-number

I have written some javascript to validate a phone number field if something is entered (it is an optional field) but it doesn't seem to be working, if i enter wrong values it still submits. Here is my code:

```
<script>
function validatePhone()
{ 
var num1 = document.getElementById('workno');

if (num1 !== null)
    {
    regex = /\(\d{2}\)\d{8}/;
    }
if (!num1.match(regex))
    {
    alert('That is not a correct telephone number format');
    return false;
    }
}
 </script>

<form name="eoiform" form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi" onsubmit="return validatePhone();">

<input type="text" id="workno" name="workno">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console log? Your script tag should have `type="text/javascript"` and your input tags should be self-closing `<input ... />`

Comment: @ogc-nick, um, no, script tag should not have `type="text/javascript`.  Nor is it necessary to self-close tags (although I think it looks nicer).  This is 2013, not 2003!

Comment: how would i check my console log?

Comment: I will make those changes as well

Comment: F12 should open Developer Tools or Firebug.

Comment: @francis, most browsers have a console you can access by pressing f12 and then making sure you're in the console tab.  Oh, and I would not make the changes ogc-nick recommends as they are not valid recommendations if you are using the html5 doctype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `num1` variable contains an element object, not its value so can't be tested with a regexp as it stands.

It will only ever by null if the element does not exist; it will be "" if its got no value.

```
function validatePhone()
{ 
  var num1 = document.getElementById('workno').value;
  if (num1 !== "" && !num1.match(/\(\d{2}\)\d{8}/))
  {
    alert('That is not a correct telephone number format');
    return false;
  }
}
```

You also have the invalid `form method="POST"` in your HTML.

Comment: The "POST" is for some PHP i have in there, I only displayed the segment of my code that was giving trouble not all of it.

Comment: Oh I just meant "form" appears twice n the <form element

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should select the value from the Input. Can you try

```
if (!num1.value.match(regex))
```

Comment: just tried it and the form is still just submitting even with wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems noted in the other answers, you should also *anchor* the regexp. Otherwise, it will allow extra characters outside the phone number.

```
function validatePhone()
{ 
  var num1 = document.getElementById('workno').value;
  if (num1 !== "" && !num1.match(/^\(\d{2}\)\d{8}$/))
  {
    alert('That is not a correct telephone number format');
    return false;
  }
}
```